# Make emacs accept period/dot from keypad?

Tags: emacs

How can I make emacs accept the period/dot from the keypad and insert a "." into the current buffer? I've managed to set-up all the numbers on the keypad using the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<kp-0>") "0")
(global-set-key (kbd "<kp-1>") "1")
...
```

But the code that emacs tells me is registered when pressing the dot key is `M-O n` rather than a `<kp-?>` key.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.` character on the keypad is normally associated to `<kp-decimal>` when NumLock is on. If NumLock is off, it corresponds to the <kbd>Del</kbd> key associated to `<kp-delete>`. In this mode, the `.` corresponds to `<S-kp-delete>`.

But, normally `<kp-0>`, `<kp-1>`, ... are already translated by default to 0, 1...

Check <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> Emacs <kbd>i</kbd> keypad <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-O n") ".")`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MaximeLorant It does for me.

Comment: Works for me, too.